# Problema ejecutando script python desde excel con xlwings

Tags: python-3.x, excel-2013

Tengo un script de Python, que ejecuto desde una hoja de Excel, mediante la siguiente macro:

```
Sub IngFinan()
    RunPython ("import Ingresos_financieros")
End Sub
```

El codigo toma los datos de una tabla de la hoja y añade al final de la misma una columna con los calculos realizados.

Cada vez que se ejecute añade una nueva columna al final de la tabla.

Mi problema es que solamente me funciona la macro una vez, me explico, si quiero ejecutar el código varias veces, cada vez tengo que cerrar y abrir el archivo Excel.

Saludos,